# Scene of imagery is missing

Tags: google-earth-engine, imagery

Sorry, i want to ask why some of imagery scene of my "area" is missing

[image]

Here is the script

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(area);
Map.centerObject(geometry,7);
var center = {lon: 109.68563619645838, lat: -7.314089282140495, zoom: 7};
Map.addLayer(Jawa)

//CLOUD MASK
function maskClouds(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
    var cloudShadowBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(3).int();
    var cloudsBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(5).int();  
    // Get the pixel QA band.
    var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
    // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
    var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0)); 
  // Return the masked image, scaled to [0, 1].
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
  }
  
//DEFINE DATASETS
  //---------------Landsat 8 Dataset---------------
  var imageL8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',90)
                  .map(maskClouds)
                  .filterBounds(area);
  //---------------Landsat 7 Dataset---------------
  var imageL7 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',90)
                  .map(maskClouds)
                  .filterBounds(area);
  //---------------Landsat 5 Dataset---------------
  var imageL5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',90)
                  .map(maskClouds)
                  .filterBounds(area);
                  
//FUNCTION INDICES
  // Indices Landsat 8
    var indicesL8 = function(a){
      //MSAVI
        var msavi = a.expression(
                    '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
                     {'NIR': a.select('B5'), // NIR: band 5
                      'RED': a.select('B4')  // RED: band 4
                     }).rename('MSAVI');
      //NDVI
        var ndvi = a.expression(
                   '(NIR - RED)/(NIR + RED)', 
                    {'NIR': a.select('B5'), // NIR: band 5
                     'RED': a.select('B4')  // RED: band 4
                    }).rename('NDVI');
      //EVI
        var evi = a.expression(
                  'float (2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)))', 
                   {'NIR': a.select('B5'), // NIR : band 5
                    'RED': a.select('B4'),  // RED : band 4
                    'BLUE' : a.select('B2') // BLUE: band 2
                   }).rename('EVI');
    return a.addBands(msavi)
            .addBands(ndvi)
            .addBands(evi);
    };
  //Indices Landsat 5 & 7
    var indicesL57 = function(a){
      //MSAVI
        var msavi = a.expression(
                    '(2 * NIR + 1 - sqrt(pow((2 * NIR + 1), 2) - 8 * (NIR - RED)) ) / 2', 
                     {'NIR': a.select('B4'), // NIR: band 4
                      'RED': a.select('B3')  // RED: band 3
                     }).rename('MSAVI');
      //NDVI
        var ndvi = a.expression(
                   '(NIR - RED)/(NIR + RED)', 
                    {'NIR': a.select('B4'), // NIR: band 4
                     'RED': a.select('B3')  // RED: band 3
                    }).rename('NDVI');
      //EVI
        var evi = a.expression(
                  'float (2.5 * ((NIR - RED) / (NIR + 6 * RED - 7.5 * BLUE + 1)))', 
                   {'NIR': a.select('B4'), // NIR : band 4
                    'RED': a.select('B3'),  // RED : band 3
                    'BLUE' : a.select('B1') // BLUE: band 5
                   }).rename('EVI');
    return a.addBands(msavi)
            .addBands(ndvi)
            .addBands(evi);
    };
      //Vis Param Indices
         var INDICESparams = {min: -1, max: 1,palette:['white','#ff0000', '#fff100','#00be13']};

// TAHUN 1994
  // Define Temporal Parameters
    var startDate_1994 = '1994-01-01';
    var endDate_1994   = '1994-12-31';
    
  // Define Satelite Datasets
    var Datasets_1994 = imageL5.filterDate(startDate_1994,endDate_1994)
                               .map(indicesL57);
  // Composite the data
    var composite_1994 = Datasets_1994.mean()
                                      .clip(geometry);
    //Display composite
    Map.addLayer(composite_1994.select(['B3', 'B2', 'B1']),{min:0.023700018388971504,max:0.12505250553765673},'Composite 1994')
```

I  have tried to delete maskCloud and change the value of 'CLOUD_COVER' to any number, but it is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that USGS does not have some scenes. Please follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help_missing_images#landsat) to report missing scenes if USGS does have them.